# check my application on tablet with server runs in the network

Tags: android, network-share

hi frnds i installed my application on my tablet. which use some web services of my server application. my tablet and PC is connected in same network.

my pc has ip address : 192.168.1.1
and my tablet has ip ; 192.168.1.6
my server application is running. but i cant connect with my server
and my server running in jBoss not in tomcat.
when i run localhost:8080.. in browser it open the jboss community page but when i give <1p address>:8080 it doesn't open the jboss community page

my Log cat :

```
05-29 09:38:08.045: W/System.err(334): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.1:8080 refused
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-29 09:38:08.081: W/System.err(334):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Comment: check whether firewall is blocking your connection or not, and if there's any logCat, you should post it too :D

Comment: Can you ping it from within adb shell?

Answer (score 1):

You must be using this command to run your server

```
                 D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\bin>run.bat
```

But this will only run on localhost not on network.So try this code to run your server

```
              D:\jboss-5.0.0.CR2\bin>run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

And then try using IP Address.I think this will solve your problem.